# Parse.com - Like system in my application

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

My like system seems a bit slow. I am going to paste the code below, but I want to explain the code first. When the user press the "likeButton" to like a content it first checks if the user already has liked the content. If the user has liked it, it unlikes the content, and if the user has not liked the content, it likes it.

```
@IBAction func likeButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.collectionView)
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(buttonPosition)

        let post = self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath!.item]

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.likeButton.enabled = false

        let query = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "userUploads", objectId: self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath!.row].objID)
        if (post.likedBy.containsObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)) {
            query.removeObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!, forKey: "likedBy")
            print("STEP 1: Current user removed from likedBy column")

            //Save
            query.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (success) {
                    // The object has been incremented
                    print("STEP 2: Successfully saved")
                    post.likedBy
                    cell.likeButton.setBackgroundImage(self.Like, forState: .Normal)
                    self.queryCurrentUploads()

                } else {
                    // There was a problem, check error.description
                    //println(error!.description)
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            query.addObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!, forKey: "likedBy")
            print("STEP 1: Current user added to likedBy column")

            // Save
            query.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (success) {
                    // The object has been incremented
                    print("STEP 2: Successfully saved")
                    cell.likeButton.setBackgroundImage(self.LikeDone, forState: .Normal)
                    self.queryCurrentUploads()

                } else {
                    // There was a problem, check error.description
                    //println(error!.description)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there anything i can do to simplify the code, because this code uses 1-2 seconds to finish, and when i look at for example Instagram it likes/unlikes in under 1 second.

Comment: So, it's not about performing the task within 1 second. Your app is taking 1-2 seconds to actually update the button. But the thing is that even in instagram, it can take that much time. First reason could be your internet connection. Second is that in instagram, the like happens instantly but in the background, it might actually 1-2 second as well. So what you can do is show the "liked" while loading itself.

Comment: The only thing that I could think of is if you put an array of likes and dislikes in the User class in Parse. The. You could use `PFUser.currentUser()["liked"] == post.text` or something like that. That would take less time to check. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets see, so you're updating your like image once you perform the checks. 
That is absolutely fine. But it would be faster if you actually kept the code before updating the objects.
For Example,

```
if (post.likedBy.containsObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)) {
            query.removeObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!, forKey: "likedBy")
            print("STEP 1: Current user removed from likedBy column")

            //Save
            query.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (success) {
                    // The object has been incremented
                    print("STEP 2: Successfully saved")
                    post.likedBy
                    cell.likeButton.setBackgroundImage(self.Like, forState: .Normal)
                    self.queryCurrentUploads()

                } else {
                    // There was a problem, check error.description
                    //println(error!.description)
                }
            }
        }
```

Instead of changing the like status after saving the objects, change it as soon as you check whether it has been liked or no.

So it can be like this,

```
 if (post.likedBy.containsObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)) {
        cell.likeButton.setBackgroundImage(self.Like, forState: .Normal)
        query.removeObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!, forKey: "likedBy")
        print("STEP 1: Current user removed from likedBy column")
                query.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (success) {
                        // The object has been incremented
                        print("STEP 2: Successfully saved")
                        post.likedBy

                        self.queryCurrentUploads()

                    } else {
                        // There was a problem, check error.description
                        //println(error!.description)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Why is it slow?
The problem is that your control open a new thread where it executes all the saving and updating task. And once that is completed, your like button's image will be updated.

Secondly,
When laoding the table view or your view with the cells, just check whether that post has been liked and hence that would decrease a little amount of time (negligible, but useful when you have a huge data set).

Hope this helps.

----EDIT----

```
@IBAction func likeButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.collectionView)
    let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(buttonPosition)

    let post = self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath!.item]

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.likeButton.enabled = false

    let query = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "userUploads", objectId: self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath!.row].objID)
    if (post.likedBy.containsObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)) {
        cell.likeButton.setBackgroundImage(self.Like, forState: .Normal)
        query.removeObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!, forKey: "likedBy")
        print("STEP 1: Current user removed from likedBy column")

        //Save
        query.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                // The object has been incremented
                cell.likeButton.enabled = true;
                print("STEP 2: Successfully saved")
                self.queryCurrentUploads()

            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
                //println(error!.description)
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        cell.likeButton.setBackgroundImage(self.LikeDone, forState: .Normal)
        query.addObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!, forKey: "likedBy")
        print("STEP 1: Current user added to likedBy column")

        // Save
        query.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                // The object has been incremented
                print("STEP 2: Successfully saved")
                cell.likeButton.enabled = true;
                self.queryCurrentUploads()

            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
                //println(error!.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I havent done much, just shifted some lines before the savInBackground function. Secondly, I've enabled the button once your querying is done. That is in the save function. 
This will be helpful because once the parse table has been updated by a like or removing like, the button will be enabled by default.

Cheers!

Comment: But there is no function for remove like in your code?

Comment: - Could you please take a look at this question i made: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801045/query-image-and-text-from-parse

Comment: I just mean to say, you do the "button image changing" operation before you start updating your parse class. I just gave an example using your code. You can do the other part as its just moving some lines of code.

Comment: What if the user press the like button really fast(?) That would mess up something i guess..

Comment: I don't think so, the only thing that can actually mess up your app is if he keeps on pressing the button again and again. Then Multiple threads would be created and the performance can actually become slow. So you even need to keep that in mind.

Comment: Do i have unlimited threads in parse.com, or what will happen if 100 users spams the like button at same time?

Comment: The threads are not on parse. Imagine, 1 click, the function gets called and all the checks are performed. "SaveInBackground" function will create a separate thread of execution. While that thread is executed, simultaneously your other code will also be executed. That is called multi threading. But if you click again and again then multiple threads will be created. And all these are on the device memory. It will not affect parse in any way. You just need to make sure that once the use clicks the button, till your parse is not updated, he cannot click it again.

Comment: Yea, that's what i was already doing! When the user clicks on the like button, it runs `button.enable = false` and when parse query is complete, it runs `button.enable = true`. I don't get how Instagram, Vine and such does this..

Comment: But can you please provide the full code for both like and unlike? :)

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll edit the code. Need to Grab my laptop.

Comment: Yea, i see it now! Thanks! Only problem: If the user tap quick 2 times in the likeButton, it crashes on this line: `let query = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "userUploads", objectId: self.objID[(indexPath?.row)!])` But if i wait one second to press, it works fine, but not if i do it quick.. I don't understand..

Comment: Strange, I think you can just hide the button for a second or so.

Comment: It would be great if you could accept the answer (Only if it helped)