# Query image and text from parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So I am create a application that users can upload images and text. The posts will be shown in UICollectionView I will provide some code for you to see below.

So my PostsViewController looks something like this:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts
import ActiveLabel

extension UILabel {
    func setSizeFont (sizeFont: CGFloat) {
        self.font =  UIFont(name: self.font.fontName, size: sizeFont)!
        self.sizeToFit()
    }
}

extension NSDate {
    var timeAgo: String {
        let minute = 60
        let hour = 60 * minute
        let day = 24 * hour
        let secondsAgo = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(self))
        if secondsAgo < 0            { return  "later"                           }
        if secondsAgo == 0           { return "now"                              }
        if secondsAgo == 1           { return "1 second ago"                     }
        if secondsAgo < minute       { return "\(secondsAgo) seconds ago"        }
        if secondsAgo < (2 * minute) { return "1 minute ago"                     }
        if secondsAgo < hour         { return "\(secondsAgo/minute) minutes ago" }
        if secondsAgo < 2 * hour     { return "1 hour ago"                       }
        if secondsAgo < day          { return "\(secondsAgo / hour) hours ago"   }
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yy"
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func makeImageWithColorAndSize(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}

struct Details {
    var username:String!
    var text:String!
    var CreatedAt:NSDate!
    var image:String!
    var objID:String!
    var likedBy:NSArray
    var comments:NSArray
    init(username:String,text:String,CreatedAt:NSDate,image:String,objID:String,likedBy:NSArray,comments:NSArray){

        self.username = username
        self.text = text
        self.CreatedAt = CreatedAt
        self.image = image
        self.objID = objID
        self.likedBy = likedBy
        self.comments = comments
    }
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, PlayerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var arrayOfDetails = [Details]()
    var likedPhotos = String()

    let Like = UIImage(named: "Like.png")
    let LikeDone = UIImage(named: "LikeDone.png")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.collectionView.delegate = self

        queryCurrentUploads()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func queryCurrentUploads() {
        self.arrayOfDetails.removeAll()
        let query = PFQuery(className: "currentUploads")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                if let newObjects = objects {

                    for oneobject in newObjects {
                        let text = oneobject["imageText"] as! String
                        let username = oneobject["username"] as! String
                        let objID = oneobject.objectId!
                        let time = oneobject.createdAt!
                        let likedBy = oneobject["likedBy"] as! NSArray
                        let comments = oneobject["comments"] as! NSArray


                        if let userImage = oneobject["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                            let userImage = oneobject["imageFile"] as! PFFile

                            let imageURL = userImage.url
                            let OneBigObject = Details(username: username, text: text, CreatedAt: time, image: imageURL!, objID: objID, likedBy: likedBy, comments: comments)

                            self.arrayOfDetails.append(OneBigObject)

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.collectionView.reloadData() }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.arrayOfDetails.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let imageCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell

        let post = self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath.row]

        imageCell?.flagContentButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        imageCell?.uploadedTimeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        imageCell?.commentsButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

        imageCell?.likeButton.enabled = true

        if (self.arrayOfDetails.count > indexPath.row) {
            imageCell?.imageText.text = post.text
            imageCell?.imageText.numberOfLines = 0
            imageCell?.imageText.verticalTextAlignmentCenter = true
            imageCell?.imageText.minFontSize = 9

            imageCell?.likeButton.setTitle(post.likedBy.count.description, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            imageCell?.commentsButton.setTitle("Comments(\(String(post.comments.count.description)))", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            imageCell?.objectID.append(post.objID)
            imageCell?.uploadedTimeLabel.text = post.CreatedAt.timeAgo

            if (post.likedBy.containsObject((PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!!)){
                imageCell?.likeButton.setBackgroundImage(self.LikeDone, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
            else{
                imageCell?.likeButton.setBackgroundImage(self.Like, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }

            imageCell?.imageView.setImageWithUrl(NSURL(string: post.image)!, placeHolderImage: UIImage(named: "Placeholder"))
        }
        return imageCell!
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width+140)
    }
}
```

And this is my CollectionViewCell.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ActiveLabel

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var imageText: ActiveLabel!
    @IBOutlet var uploadedTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var flagContentButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var likeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var commentsButton: UIButton!

    var objectID = [String]()
}
```

This is how my class in Parse.com looks like:
[image]

So my question is: Is there any faster or more simple/easy way to get the data from Parse.com, and to my UICollectionView?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I added some of my code below to keep it as clean as possible.

The biggest structural thing you could do is just drop the received PFObjects into an array and use that array to populate your collection view. I see no need for parsing into that secondary object.

```
var spotsArray = [PFObject]()

func getParseData(){
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Places")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        self.spotsArray = objects!
        self.spotsCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
    if refreshControl.refreshing {
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return spotsArray.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpotsCell

    let currentSpot = spotsArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.titleLabel.text = (currentSpot["Title"] as! String)

    if let descTemp = (currentSpot["Desc"] as? String){
        cell.descLabel.text = descTemp

        let userImageFile = currentSpot["imageFile"] as! PFFile
        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    cell.selectedImageView.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                }

            } 
        }
    }

    return cell

}
```

The code above is from the project [here.](https://github.com/wagnercasey/SightCR)

Comment: Ok, i tried to edit my own code, take a look here: http://pastebin.com/Ayvxbu2x - Please tell me what you think of it now.

Comment: Do check out my [project](https://github.com/wagnercasey/SightCR) I have on Github, it's very similar to what you are doing.